# C# casting derived generic type to parent

Tags: c#, generics, downcast

Before I ask my question this is my structure:

```
public class Data : ScriptableObject {...}
public class ItemData : Data {...}
public class WeaponData : ItemData {...}

public abstract class Item<T> : Visual<T> where T : ItemData {...}
public class Weapon<T> : Item<T> where T : WeaponData {...}
```

I get an error (Cannot cast from source type to destination type) when I create a `Weapon` object and assign it to `Item<ItemData>`.

```
Weapon<Foo> weapon = new Weapon<Foo>();
Item<ItemData> other = weapon;
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C#, covariance (assigning a derived type to a base type) cannot be applied to generic classes.  As a result, you would need to apply an interface specifically marked as covariant, using the [out parameter modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) on a new `IItem` interface.

However, that by itself isn't enough.  You do not have a way to tell `Item` that it will allow an instance of `Weapon` to be assigned to it when `Weapon` has a generic type parameter that could be ***anything*** provided it inherits from `ItemData`.  This places the compiler in a difficult predicament since it can't assure you that the relationship is valid.  However, if you apply a new `IItemData` interface to `ItemData`, the cast will be permissible.

```
void Main()
{
    Weapon<Foo> weapon = new Weapon<Foo>();
    IItem<ItemData> other = weapon;
}

public interface IItem<out T> {}
public interface IItemData {}

public class Foo : WeaponData {}

public class Data : ScriptableObject {}
public class ItemData : Data, IItemData {}
public class WeaponData : ItemData {}

public abstract class Item<T> : Visual<T>, IItem<T> where T : IItemData {}
public class Weapon<T> : Item<T> where T : WeaponData {}

public class ScriptableObject {}
public class Visual<T> {}
```

This requires `Item<T>` be updated to be constrained to `IItemData` instead of constrained to a concrete type.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with that, I just never had the problem actually come up. Thanks +1

Comment: @HectorLlanos Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Generics get all weird when you deal with this kind of stuff. I've not investigated this in C#, but if it's anything like Java - which I suspect it is - *you can only set a variable of a given generic type if the generic parameters match.* For example, other would have to be an Item of type Foo (`Item<Foo>`), not of type `ItemData`. The reason goes something like this:

```
class A {...}
class B : A {...}
class C {
    public static void main(string[] args) {
        List<B> BL = new List<B>();
        List<A> AL = BL;
        AL.Add(new A()); // Now the List of B instances has an A instance in it!!
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to do something like Java's `List<? extends A>` in C#, though. That would be the Java-type solution.